# Display an image (tinyblob) stored in a database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I try to read image from database (blob) but i have problem becouse i don't know mime type of image. I have only tinyblob.

Can i read image and save it back to my hard disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is to store the mime-type in the DB at the same time you're inserting the image into the blob field. Otherwise you're going to have to the following EACH TIME the image is retrieved:

```
$image = $row['imageblob'];  // $row = result row from DB query.

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime_type = $finfo->buffer($image);
```

This gets to be expensive very quickly on a busy system, so best do the determination ONCE and then store that result.

Relevant [PHP docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php).

Answer (score 1):

Why not store the images on the hard disk all the time, and store in the Database a relative link based on a known directory?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that I have used to get a logo (blob) from a mysql database

```
<a href="index.php"><img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($MyClass->getLogo())?>" alt="Logo" width="233" height="65" /></a>
```

And the getLogo() function

```
 public function getLogo()
    {
        if ($this->getId())
            $query = "SELECT `logo` FROM Logos WHERE `logo_id` = '{$this->getId()}' LIMIT 1";
        else
            $query = "SELECT `logo` FROM Logos WHERE `logo_id` = '1' LIMIT 1";

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($result)
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        else
            return NULL;                    

        return ($row['logo']);
    }
```